# typeof object.constructor always returns a function. Is that true?

Tags: javascript

```
function Person(name){
 this.name = name;
}

p = new Person('John');
log(typeof p.constructor);

var f = {};
log(typeof f.constructor);

var f2 = new Object();
log(typeof f2.constructor);
```

All three log statements show 'function'.

Is there a case when the constructor of an object will NOT be 'function' ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A constructor is a function in javascript, **by definition**. So the type will always be "function".

See: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_constructor_math.asp

"*The constructor property is a reference to the function that created an object.*"

The [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Object/constructor) is even clearer:

*Returns a reference to the Object function that created the instance's prototype. Note that the value of this property is a reference to the function itself, not a string containing the function's name*

Answer (score 0):

An object constructor is merely a regular JavaScript function, so it's just as robust (ie: define parameters, call other functions etc). The difference between the two is that a constructor function is called via the new operator

Read

[Object Constructor and prototyping](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/oopjs2.shtml)